# Deleting an element from an array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, valgrind

I have an array of pointers to structs, and what I want to do is delete an element and shift all the rest to fill the gap. I have written a function which seems to work, however valgrind complains about 'invalid read/write of size 8' so now I'm wondering if what I did was incorrect.

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = (numOfApartments-1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if (apartmentIsIdentical(apartment, apartmentArray[i]->apartment)) {
        apartmentDestroy(apartmentArray[i]->apartment);
        free(apartmentArray[i]);
        shiftApartments(apartmentArray, i, numOfApartments);
        numOfApartments--;
        return 1;
    }
}

static void shiftApartments(ApartmentInfo* array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        swapApartments(&array[i], &array[i + 1]);
    }
}

static void swapApartments(ApartmentInfo* apartment1, ApartmentInfo* apartment2) {
    ApartmentInfo temp = *apartment1;
    *apartment1 = *apartment2;
    *apartment2 = temp;
}
```

My question is mainly whether the free(apartmentArray[i]) is correct. The way I see it, it should leave an empty slot which I just move to the end of the array and place something else there later. However the error of 'invalid read/write of size 8' made me wonder whether freeing apartmentArray[i] actually make the slot inaccessible..? Why does it say I can't write to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The code seems not to use am array of pointer, but an array of `ApartmentInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

since you freed apartmentArray[i], you cant swap the values, just assign the pointer in shiftApartments

try to replace

```
swapApartments(&array[i], &array[i + 1]);
```

with

```
array[i] = array[i+1];
```

Comment: So how do I delete an element if I can't swap the values? I didn't quite understand what "just assign the pointer in shiftApartments" means. Would it work if I first shift the elements and then use free? would I be able to use that slot again?

Answer (score 0):

`memmove()` is your friend here. Memmove handles the cases of overlapping moves, and can avoid an explicit loop. The only difficulty is to get the sizes right!

(I use an array of pointers to character, but this is essentially not different from pointers to struct. Except that you should not attempt to free() them ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char *array[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four"
                , "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };

        /* using an array of pointers to string literals
        ** , so free() should not be used here ...
        */
#define SHOULDFREE(s) fprintf(stderr,"Should free %s\n", s)

unsigned size = 8;
unsigned idx,top;

for (top=idx=size; idx-- > 0;   ) {
                /* only delete words that start with 't' */
        if (*array[idx] != 't') continue;
        SHOULDFREE(array[idx]);
        top--;
        if (idx >=top) continue;
        fprintf(stderr,"about to move %u (%s) (%u elements) one place down\n"
                        , idx+1, array[idx+1], top-idx);
        memmove( &array[idx], &array[idx+1], (top-idx) * sizeof array[0] );
        }
for (idx=0; idx < top; idx++) {
        printf("[%u]: %s\n", idx, array[idx] );
        }
return 0;
}
```

And, of course the

`memmove( &array[idx], &array[idx+1], (top-idx) * sizeof array[0] );`

could be replaced by:

`memmove( array+idx, array+idx+1, (top-idx) * sizeof array[0] );`